# IDA pro obfuscation instance

Tags: disassembly, obfuscation

I have tried all the I have learned so far to figure out how to deal with this instance of obfuscation.
[image]

So far I understand that an opaque predicate is present, causing an unconditional jump to one byte into L0.

What I don't understand is how to deal with this issue in IDA. If the jump is made to L0+1 how can I mark the byte E8 as data, or deal with this otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA is good at recognising such tricks, but if it didn't
you can press <kbd>D</kbd> having the `call` instruction selected.

This will convert the opcode to a data, displaying just bunch of `db`s. After that, select the byte that has `db 58` (so one after `E8`) and press <kbd>C</kbd> to convert it to code again without the first byte.

Result after the changes.

[image]

I don't know if this could be automated - probably with some script that IDA supports it could be.